# Using an NSPredicate to tell if an NSSet contains objects from another NSSet

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsset, nsexception

I have a Core Data object that has an NSOrderedSet of Core Data objects in it called hierarchyItems. I want to create a fetch request that will check to see if the hierarchyItems set contains an object that is also in another NSMutableSet of Core Data objects.I would like to create a NSPredicate or NSExpression that has the same functionality as

```
[obj.hierarchyItems intersectsSet: setOfItems];
```

Comment: It does not look like a duplicate to me. This question is about set intersection, which is actually easier to test for than set equality.

Comment: @MartinR: set equality testing is quite trivially derived from set intersection

Comment: @njzk2: I do not quite understand what you mean. The question was about Core Data predicates (which have only a limited set of available operators). As you can see from the answer to the "possible duplicate", finding all objects whose relationship is *equal* to a given set is more complicated than the solution to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fetch the object for which `hierarchyItems` has a non-empty intersection with 
`setOfItems`, use a fetch request with the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY hierarchyItems IN %@", setOfItems]
```

Comment: Sadly no this does not work. I have tried this to no avail.

Comment: @user3200440: Well, I have tested it and it worked for me. - Can you provide more information? How are the entities defined, relationships etc. Do you get an error message, no results, wrong results ... ?

Comment: I agree that should work perfectly and I don't know why it doesn't. There are no error messages, I just get an empty array back. Before you ask yes there are overlapping objects between the two sets.

Comment: @user3200440: Just to locate the problem: Does it work if you fetch all objects (without any predicate) and then filter the fetched array using the above predicate?