# CoreData fetch predicate using a set intersection

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, set-intersection

My core data model has an entity with an attribute `setOfStrings` of type `Transformable`.
The corresponding class has a property `@NSManaged var setOfStrings: Set<String>?`.
I want to fetch objects using a predicate that filters out objects where their attribute `setOfStrings` has a set intersection with a given set, say `givenSet`.
I tried to use the following predicate:

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY setOfStrings IN %@", givenSet)
```

but it always evaluates to `false`.
If I out comment this predicate, the unfiltered objects are correctly fetched.
I read many SO Q/A related to this subject, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154554/1987726). However it does not work.
I know, if my attribute `setOfStrings` would be a relation, I could use a subquery to fetch the right objects, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22102471/1987726). But I don’t have a relation, just a set of strings.
I have also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25435867/1987726) that says

> I assume that the set is defined as a transformable property, which
> means that it is stored as a binary archive in the SQLite file. Then
> the above queries will work at most for objects already loaded into
> the managed object context, but not against the store file.

This is obviously related to my problem. But the suggested solution to replace a simple set of strings by a to-many relation seems to me too complicated.
Which predicate should I use?

Comment: I'm afraid a predicate based on a transformable attribute just won't work as part of a fetch.  You've either got to fetch everything, and then filter the results in memory, or use a different type of property: a to-many relationship would be best, but you might be able to concatenate your strings into a single string and store that.  Then your predicate might work against that.  But it depends on the details of the strings.

Comment: @pbasdf Should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid a predicate based on a transformable attribute just won't work as part of a fetch. You've either got to fetch everything, and then filter the results in memory, or use a different type of property: a to-many relationship would be best, but you might be able to concatenate your strings into a single string and store that. Then your predicate might work against that.

But it depends on the details of the strings.  For example, if they are single words, like colours: "red", "green", "blue", "cyan", etc, then you can concatenate them with spaces and store a single string:

```
"red green blue cyan"
```

(Of course, you then have to add code to separate them again wherever the individual colours are required).

Suppose you then want to use a predicate to find those objects with either "green" or "blue".  You would then construct a predicate along these lines:

```
colourString CONTAINS "blue" OR colourString CONTAINS "green"
```

If your strings or your search criteria are more complicated, then a different means of concatenation might be necessary.  For example, if you have multi-word colours, like "pale green", "pale yellow", a search for "green" might match "dark green", "pale green" etc (which might be good or bad).  If that's bad, you might need to use a different delimiter (eg. a comma) then your string might be:

```
"red,blue,pale green,cyan"
```

and your predicate to find the colour "green", but not "pale green" would be:

```
colourString CONTAINS ",green,"
```

though there are then the nasty edge cases where "green" is the first or last colour, so you need include a leading and trailing comma in your colourString:

```
",red,blue,pale green,cyan,"
```

which is starting to get increasingly messy.  And if your strings might contain commas already, a different delimiter and more complicated predicates will be required.  Depending on your data, it may be that a to-many relationship is easier.

Comment: Thanks for your details explanation! I was simply not aware that "Transformable" means "Convert to NSData".